# AWS - Get Windows password for EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, rdp, terminal

I'm trying to receive the default Windows password so I can RDP into my EC2 instance. According to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html), it's just as simple as sharing the contents of the Key Pair that used during the creation of the instance.

However when I do that, I get the following error:

[image: There was an error decrypting your password. Please ensure that your private key is not encrypted.]

Looking at my .pem file, the contents do appear to be encrypted:

[image]

So I've tried to decrypt the RSA key using the following command in macOS (taken from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/603984/windows-password-wont-decrypt-on-aws-ec2-even-with-the-correct-private-key)):

`base64 -D -i /Users/home/desktop/pw.txt | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey $HOME/aws-remote.pem`

But I keep getting the following error in Terminal:

> Error reading input Data

The .pem file is being found OK (it gives another error if it can't find it). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've moved this over from SO because it was the wrong SE for this type of question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Password won't decrypt on AWS EC2 even with the correct private key](https://serverfault.com/questions/603984/windows-password-wont-decrypt-on-aws-ec2-even-with-the-correct-private-key)

Comment: @LucaGibelli I literally linked to that question in my answer and explained how it didn't solve me problem :-/

Comment: Well, but you do admit that the question is the same :) the answers might not solve your problem, but the question is the same

Comment: @LucaGibelli The accepted solution in that question doesn't solve my problem, ergo the problem is actually different. If the problem is different, it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started searching for other solutions and came across something which fixed the problem for me:

`openssl rsa -in $HOME/.ssh/aws-remote -out /Users/home/desktop/unecrypted-rsa.txt`

Amazon was happy and I got my Windows password. Woo!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .ppk file, you can convert it to .pem using PuttyGen.

1. Load your .ppk file:
   [image]
2. Export it as OpenSSH format:
   [image]